# Apache and RewriteRule

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a domain url, `myDomain.com`

Under this domain I have Tomcat with application `/app/`

Additionally I have apache with `mod_jk` which is handled before Tomcat.

To open my application I have to go to `myDomain.com/app/{something}`.

How to create auto redirect or rewrite so that everything what will be open under `myDomain.com/app/{something}` will by auto-redirected to `myDomain.com/{something}`?

I want to cut off `/app/` from url.

I can do:

```
Redirect /app/ /
```

But the next problem is that everything what I have under `/` I want push to `/app/`, so I have:

```
RewriteRule ^/$ /app/ [P]
RewriteRule ^/([A-Za-z0-9\_]+)$ /app/$1 [P]
```

But when I'm using `Redirect` and `RewriteRule` like above, I have a loop and it doesn't work.

Comment: You mean redirect `myDomain.com/{something}` to `myDomain.com/app/{something}` so that it can be handled by Tomcat? Not the other way round?

Comment: Also, where do you do the rewrite? In `.htaccess` or in the server / host configuration of Apache2?